# how to get total comments/likes count? (Facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Eg. I wanna get an album's information by graph api (me/albums )

The result didnt include comments  / likes total count.

Also somebody says:

you must provide a parameter named "post_id"

However, albums has no "post_id".

I use graph path: "uid/feed"  or  "me/home"

The fb server returns result include total count.

I'm desired to know an object's total comments/likes count.(albums/photo/video)

Plz share your any idea with us,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use something like this as the URL to fetch what you need:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/albumID/photos?fields=id,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)&access_token=XXXXXX
```

Here is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085722/how-to-count-all-of-the-likes-and-comments-in-a-facebook-photo-album) that details a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `/id/<connection>` to retrieve this data. First get the id of the album (using `/me/albums` or `/<uid>/albums`) you want to get likes/comments for and then call following url for getting likes:

`https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/likes?access_token=...`

for comments:

`https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/comments?access_token=...`

Comment: id/likes || id/comments  doesn't work fine. The result just include "data" & "paging"

Comment: then probably the albums don't have comments/like. Use facebook graph api explorer to check the result api call.